# CodeIgniter Resize image

Tags: codeigniter

My script is:

```
public function resize_image($dir, $new_name, $image, $width, $height)
{
$img_cfg_thumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$img_cfg_thumb['source_image'] = "./" . $dir . "/" . $image;
$img_cfg_thumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$img_cfg_thumb['new_image'] = $new_name;
$img_cfg_thumb['width'] = 200;
$img_cfg_thumb['height'] = 200;
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($img_cfg_thumb);
$this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

but it only create thumbnail of **200 x 150**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What size is your ORIGINAL image?

Because

```
 $img_cfg_thumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
```

Try and set that to false